# Article layout with CSS Grid: how to wrap text around images (or float them)?

Tags: css, css-grid

I know that direct children of a grid item cannot be floated. I'm trying to create an article layout where something like this is achieved: pull an image to either side, and have the text flow around it.

[Here's what I have so far on Codepen](https://codepen.io/minttoothpick/pen/jObpeMb). With named template columns, I can have an image fill up only part of the width of the grid, but is there *any* way to let the surrounding text flow around it?

Hopefully my Codepen example makes sense; please let me know if I can provide additional information or clarification!

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

article {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [wide-start] minmax(1em, 1fr) [main-start] minmax(0, 16em) [main-half] minmax(0, 16em) [main-end] minmax(1em, 1fr) [wide-end];
}

article>* {
  grid-column: main;
}

figure {
  grid-column: wide-start / main-half;
}

div {
  grid-column: main-half / main-end;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Article</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore dolorem porro vero! In iste nemo repellendus? Doloremque eius officia beatae doloribus autem vitae enim qui. Minus, facere? Quaerat, laboriosam enim?</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <figcaption>
      <p>I wish the text could wrap around to my right</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, obcaecati, blanditiis ad nostrum autem atque error quasi, tempora debitis exercitationem illum. Maiores cum delectus, fugit repellat provident libero hic magni?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates consectetur aspernatur est numquam alias consequatur praesentium quaerat totam dicta non asperiores similique inventore, a perspiciatis perferendis laudantium minus ratione animi!</p>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
    <figcaption>
      <p>Text is now in a column next to me (because I wrapped it in a <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>, but it won't wrap underneath me automatically</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fugiat repellat consequatur, voluptas sint eum ea error sit hic dignissimos expedita totam suscipit officia consequuntur non, quaerat odio. Recusandae, consequatur maxime!</p>
    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet, pariatur ipsa fuga hic nihil unde maiores, provident eius minima atque accusamus voluptate aspernatur perferendis. Ab rem inventore omnis at!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At vitae ex fugit sequi, natus asperiores? Laudantium optio, doloribus error dolores exercitationem aliquid esse, reiciendis mollitia alias vel illo, amet officiis?</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS grid because it's not a grid. As you said, you need float

Comment: You can if you nest your elements https://jsfiddle.net/f6v9xmqk/

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly and you don't have to use only CSS Gird for the whole layout you can wrap your figure and paragraphs in another div, then trough that div give your figure max width of 50%, float:left, and some margin-right... you get the point.

```css
figure { margin: 0; }
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }

article {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    [wide-start] minmax(1em, 1fr)
    [main-start] minmax(0, 16em)
    [main-half] minmax(0, 16em) [main-end]
    minmax(1em, 1fr) [wide-end];
}

article > * {
  grid-column: main;
}


.floating{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.floating figure {
  float:left;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
  
.floating p {
    margin-top:0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <h1>Article</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore dolorem porro vero! In iste nemo repellendus? Doloremque eius officia beatae doloribus autem vitae enim qui. Minus, facere? Quaerat, laboriosam enim?</p>
  <div class="floating">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
      <figcaption>
        <p>I wish the text could wrap around to my right</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, obcaecati, blanditiis ad nostrum autem atque error quasi, tempora debitis exercitationem illum. Maiores cum delectus, fugit repellat provident libero hic magni?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates consectetur aspernatur est numquam alias consequatur praesentium quaerat totam dicta non asperiores similique inventore, a perspiciatis perferendis laudantium minus ratione animi!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="floating">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x300">
      <figcaption>
        <p>Text is now in a column next to me (because I wrapped it in a <code>&lt;div&gt;</code>, but it won't wrap underneath me automatically</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fugiat repellat consequatur, voluptas sint eum ea error sit hic dignissimos expedita totam suscipit officia consequuntur non, quaerat odio. Recusandae, consequatur maxime!</p>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque eveniet, pariatur ipsa fuga hic nihil unde maiores, provident eius minima atque accusamus voluptate aspernatur perferendis. Ab rem inventore omnis at!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At vitae ex fugit sequi, natus asperiores? Laudantium optio, doloribus error dolores exercitationem aliquid esse, reiciendis mollitia alias vel illo, amet officiis?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```